# Query in Waterline using a model as a criteria

Tags: node.js, mongodb, model, sails.js, waterline

I just started to work with Waterline and I got question about search for records in a database Mongo using a model as criteria. After some hours of search I couldn't find any satisfactory solution.

First, I have basically 2 model related between themselves:

Post.js

```
var Post = Waterline.Collection.extend({
tableName: 'Post',
connection: 'default',
attributes: {
    url : { type: 'string', required: true, unique: true, lowercase: true },
    title : { type: 'string', required: true },
    body : { type: 'string', required: true },
    author : { type: 'string', required: true },
    writeIn : { type: 'string', required: true },
    tags: {
        collection: 'Tag',
        via: 'posts',
        dominant: true
    },
    category: {
        model: 'Category'
    }
}});
```

Category.js

```
var Category = Waterline.Collection.extend({
tableName: 'Category',
connection: 'default',
attributes: {
    url: { type: 'string', required: true, unique: true, lowercase: true },
    name: { type: 'string', required: true },
    posts: {
        collection: 'Post',
        via: 'category'
    }
}});
```

They are related using Many-to-Many association. The point is that I would like to query a list of posts through a category name.
Something like this:

```
Post.find().where({category: {url: 'java'}})
```

Does any of you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by different way...

```
Category.find()
     .where({url: 'java'})
        .populate('posts')
```